# FirebirdSQL Unique & Max (or MaxValue)

Tags: sql, max, unique, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

I want to run a report from sales of any customer that has ordered in the last two years.

I can run a report of all invoices dated within two years then remove duplicates in excel, but I would rather do it directly within (Firebird) SQL

I can use a `WHERE date < 1 Jan 2015` (2 years or thereabours), but how do I get it to only show the customer once? I thought if I used `MAX(Date)` therefore showing the most recent date in that two year period. Where am I going wrong? I believe I need to use a `UNIQUE()` function like `UNIQUE(ORDERCUSTOMER)` within the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT
FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.TRANSACTIONDATE,
FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.INVOICECUSTOMER, 
FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.ORDERCUSTOMER,
FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.INVOICENUMBER,
FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.SOURCENUMBER,
MAX(FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.TRANSACTIONDATE)

FROM FINANCIALSALESINVOICES 
WHERE (FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.TRANSACTIONDATE>={d '2015-01-01'})
ORDER BY FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.INVOICECUSTOMER, FINANCIALSALESINVOICES.TRANSACTIONDATE
```

I did having it showing the max date for each instance of invoice in the past two years, but now can't fine that file or replicate it.

Comment: Which column in `FINANCIALSALESINVOICES` identifies a particular customer?  You never made this clear.

Comment: So you want to show the latest invoice per customer? Is this what you are saying? And with customer you mean the `INVOICECUSTOMER` or the `ORDERCUSTOMER` here?

Comment: The ordercustomer.

The purpose of the report if for a mail out, which will be ongoing.  If I have the customer's who ordered in the past two years only appear once then we can create mail labels or email (or whatever the marking dept want).

Comment: @SimonKing this question seems resolved to me.  Please convey to the Stack Overflow community that your question is sufficiently resolved by awarding the green tick to the answer that you found most helpful.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause which checks for the most recent invoice:

```
SELECT
    t.TRANSACTIONDATE,
    t.INVOICECUSTOMER, 
    t.ORDERCUSTOMER,
    t.INVOICENUMBER,
    t.SOURCENUMBER
FROM FINANCIALSALESINVOICES t
WHERE t.TRANSACTIONDATE >= date '2015-01-01' AND
      t.TRANSACTIONDATE = (SELECT MAX(f.TRANSACTIONDATE)
                           FROM FINANCIALSALESINVOICES f
                           WHERE t.ORDERCUSTOMER = f.ORDERCUSTOMER AND
                                 f.TRANSACTIONDATE >= date '2015-01-01')
ORDER BY t.INVOICECUSTOMER,
         t.TRANSACTIONDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

With Firebird 3 you can use `row_number()` to assign a unique value to each row within a group (partition), that value can then be filtered on:

```
select 
    a.TRANSACTIONDATE,
    a.INVOICECUSTOMER, 
    a.ORDERCUSTOMER,
    a.INVOICENUMBER,
    a.SOURCENUMBER
from (
    select
        TRANSACTIONDATE,
        INVOICECUSTOMER, 
        ORDERCUSTOMER,
        INVOICENUMBER,
        SOURCENUMBER,
        row_number() over (partition by INVOICECUSTOMER, order by TRANSACTIONDATE desc) as rownr
    from FINANCIALSALESINVOICES
    where TRANSACTIONDATE >= date '2015-01-01'
) a
where a.rownr = 1
order by a.INVOICECUSTOMER, a.TRANSACTIONDATE
```

See also [Window (Analytical) Functions](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html) in the Firebird 3 release notes.

Comment: This is a nice alternative assuming the OP's version of Firebird supports row number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agreed, that is a big if, but they'll always have your answer to fall back to.

Comment: Unfortunately Ostendo runs on Firebird v2.5 (64 bit). Though, Good to know for the future.